# How to delete Lazarus completely?

Tags: configuration, uninstall, lazarus

Some time ago Lazarus began to work incorrect ("the project uses target OS Linux and i386"). It doesn't work at all now - I can't compile even an empty program. I tried to remove Lazarus several times. But after new installation I have the same problem. In the past I hadn't such problem.

What does in mean? I think, some components of Lazarus remain after the removal of Lazarus. I tried to use Synaptic, apt-get remove/autoremove/purge, but useless.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

There may be old Lazarus configuration files in your home folder.

I'm not familiar with Lazarus so you'll have to experiment a bit. Open your home folder, click **View ▸ Show Hidden Files**, and then look for anything related to Lazarus:

- [`~/.config/fppkg.cfg`](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/fppkg#The_global_configuration_file)
- [`~/.ppc386.cfg`](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Faq#When_compiling_lazarus_the_compiler_can_not_find_a_unit._e.g.%3a_gtkint.pp.2817.2C16.29_Fatal%3a_Can.27t_find_unit_GLIB)
- [`~/.fpc.cfg`](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Faq#When_compiling_lazarus_the_compiler_can_not_find_a_unit._e.g.%3a_gtkint.pp.2817.2C16.29_Fatal%3a_Can.27t_find_unit_GLIB)

If any of these exist, try disabling them by trashing or renaming them to restore Lazarus to its default configuration.